# How to count the number of times a string appears in an array without using maps?

Tags: java, collections, counting

I am trying to count the number of times a string appears in an array, but I cannot use any type of Map. From my research, I tried the following expecting it to work:

```
int count = Collections.frequency(strings, search);
```

However, when I got an error when running the program. The error was a Null Pointer Exception error and I'm not sure how to fix that or why it happened. Any ideas on whats wrong with my code?

EDIT: Here's my full code. I can't find where the issue lies. Maybe someone else can find it 
    import java.util.*;

public class Lab9 {

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
     Scanner kb =  new Scanner (System.in);
     String name = null;
     List<String> strings =null;
     System.out.println("How many strings do you want to enter?:");
     int size = kb.nextInt();

     List<String> String = getStrings(size,name);
     System.out.println(String);
     System.out.println("What string would you like to search for?:");
     String search = kb.next();

     int numofTimes = countValues (search,strings);
     System.out.print("That word appears "+numofTimes+" times in the array.");


 }
 public static List<String> getStrings(int size,String name) {
     Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
     int count = 0;
     List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
     while (count != size) {
         System.out.println("Enter a string:");
         name = kb.nextLine();
         strings.add(name);
         count = count + 1;
          }

return strings;

 }
 public static int countValues (String search, List<String> strings){

     int count = Collections.frequency(strings , search);



     return count;
 }



 }
```

Comment: `NullPointerException --This is thrown if c is null.`  [source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_frequency.htm) (c in this example being `strings`)

Comment: the array is being used as a parameter, and is created in another method. Why is it null? Here's more of the code:
     `code` public static int countValues (String search, List<String> String){
   
   int count = Collections.frequency(String, search);
   
   
   
   return count;
  } `code`

Comment: Please don't post code via comments, edit your question :) much cleaner and easier to read

Answer (score 1):

You can do a linear search through the array

```
    String strings[] = {"A","B",null,"C","A",null}; // the array contains nulls
    String search = "A";
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i< strings.length ;i++ ) 
    {
        if(strings[i] != null)
        {
            if(strings[i].equals(search))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }                   
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a null and size check on `strings` before using it:

```
if (strings != null && strings.size() > 0) {
    int count = Collections.frequency(strings, search);
}
```

If `size()` returns a number larger than 0 that means your `strings` has something in it and you can perform `frequency()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_frequency.htm

There's a good example of the use of frequency(Collection c, Object o);

The nullpointerexception can occur if one of the values in your collection is null. Are you sure that the excpetion is at the line of your frequency?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for [`Collections.frequency()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Object-):

```
public static int frequency(Collection<?> c, Object o) {
    int result = 0;
    if (o == null) {
        for (Object e : c)
            if (e == null)
                result++;
    } else {
        for (Object e : c)
            if (o.equals(e))
                result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

As you can see, it is able to deal with `o == null` and with `c` containing `null` elements. The only case it will throw a `NullPointerException` is when `c == null`.

Also, from the documentation:

> **frequency**
>
> public static int frequency(Collection c, Object o)
>
> **Throws:**
>
> - NullPointerException - if c is null